# With a only button expand other buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button

I have a lot of buttons on my page HTML. All of these buttons expand some information when you click on the button.

To make it more useful, I want with a only button, expand the others buttons.

First I try to only show one button with the main button, after I will do for the others.

That's what I have done til now, it shows different but it doesn't collapse.

```
               <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="collapseEveryButtons" data-target="collapseEveryButtons" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="MonCollapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i> Collapse</button>

                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="collapseForm1" data-target="#collapseForm1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="MonCollapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i> Form1</button>
                <div id="collapseForm1" class="collapse">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name1">Name :</label><br>
                        <input type="text" style="background-color:#bfbfbf;" disabled name="name1" class="form-control" id="name1" value="<?php echo $name1;?>">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email :</label><br>
                        <input type="text" style="background-color:#bfbfbf;" disabled name="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
                    </div>
               </div>

                   <script type="text/javascript">
                    <!-- Change the color of the button when it's open-->
                        $('#collapseEveryButtons').click( function(){
                            $('#Form1').find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down');
                            $('.btn btn-open').not(this).removeClass('btn-open');
                            $('#collapseAnneesRenovation').toggleClass('btn-open-collapsed');
                            $("#collapseAnneesRenovation").attr("aria-expanded",true);
                            var $collapse = $('#collapseAnneesRenovation').find('.collapse');
                            $collapse.collapse('toggle');
                        });
                    </script>
```

This show how to open one button only

```
                       $('#collapseForm1,#collapse2,#collapse3').click( function(){
                            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down');
                            $('.btn btn-open').not(this).removeClass('btn-open');
                            $(this).toggleClass('btn-open');
                        });
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Expand buttons` ....? How? What are you trying to achieve? Your question is unclear...Please create a runnable snippet that shows your problem.

Comment: you should alway put variable name, comment, class names ... in english. or at least, put them in inglish here. a lot of non french people will read your code and don't understand it

Comment: Ok, I change it in english. I'm not fluent English so I do my best. The thing a lot of buttons opens forms, but you need to open one by one. I just want to open all the buttons with one main button. Hope you understood

Answer (score 0):

It's ok I resolve it but it still a problem

```
<div id="anneesRenovationCollapse" class="collapse">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name :</label><br>
                            <input type="text" style="background-color:#bfbfbf;" disabled name="name" class="form-control" id="immeuble_n_anne_toit" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
                        </div> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
                        $('#collapseEveryButtons').click( function(){
                        $('#collapseAnneesRenovation').find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down');
                        $('.btn btn-open').not(this).removeClass('btn-open');
                        $('#collapseAnneesRenovation').toggleClass('btn-open-collapsed');
                        $("#collapseAnneesRenovation").attr("aria-expanded",true);
                        $('#anneesRenovationCollapse').find('.collapse');
                        $('#anneesRenovationCollapse').toggleClass('collapse collapse in');
});
</script>
```

Now I open all the buttons with the main one "anneesRenovationCollapse" BUT when a button it's already opened, it will closed the button and open the ones that are closed. Hope you understood.